# Magnifying a portion of an image in figure

Tags: floats, magnification

I exactly want to creat this:

[image]

I read about zoomboxarray or spy package, but I'm looking for a simple way, like just a tabular solution, is there such a way?

Creating a rectangle around left image wouldn't be hard I guess, on the right hand, there are different images with the same size of left images but magnified on the yellow area.

```
    \begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[zoomboxarray,
    zoomboxarray columns=1,
    zoomboxarray rows=1,
    connect zoomboxes,
    zoombox paths/.append style={line width=3pt}
    zoombox paths/.append style={ultra thick, red}]
    \node [image node] { \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/noisy.png} };
    \zoombox[magnification=2]{0.45,0.67}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Noisy}
\label{fig:noisy}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[zoomboxarray,
    zoomboxarray columns=1,
    zoomboxarray rows=1,
    connect zoomboxes,
    zoombox paths/.append style={line width=3pt}
    zoombox paths/.append style={ultra thick, red}]
    \node [image node] { \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/bilateral.png} };
    \zoombox[magnification=2]{0.45,0.67}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{bilateral flilter output}
\label{fig:noisy}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[zoomboxarray,
    zoomboxarray columns=1,
    zoomboxarray rows=1,
    connect zoomboxes,
    zoombox paths/.append style={line width=3pt}
    zoombox paths/.append style={ultra thick, red}]
    \node [image node] { \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/output.png} };
    \zoombox[magnification=2]{0.45,0.67}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Model output}
\label{fig:noisy}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you got so far and what problem are you running into? The images on the right differ, so they're not simple magnifications are they?

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I put a code snippet that I tried to change but it is not the same to my output at all..

Comment: Can you make it copy-paste-compile-able? Then it is easier for people to help.